# Is there a way to download files from the Internet using the windows shell?

Tags: windows, shell, download

Like wget or curl, but without having to install either of those progs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jupp, if you are using Windows 7 Powershell should be installed by default so then you open a shell and type

```
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("URL", "filename")
```

to download the resource at the specified *URL* to your disk using the supplied *filename*.

If you do this frequently then it might be worthwhile to create a function in your Powershell profile. To do this, create the file %UserProfile%\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 and add for instance the following function

```
function download-file { 
   param($url, $filename) 
   (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $filename)
}
```

Then you can download a file from Powershell through the slightly more convenient `download-file "url" "filename"`.

Answer (score 5):

You mean like the wget [over here](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: I would suggest this port of wget: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm (which doesn't have a 4GB file limit).

Answer (score 2):

Look Here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146973/powershell-script-to-download-file-having-trouble-setting-up-a-secure-connection